# Inner Join String & Integer Value both in 1 column in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, ado, vba

Please find my below table and VBA code.

**table 1:-**

[image]

**table 2:-**

[image]

**Required Output**

[image]

I am getting **Type Mismatch in expression.** error and i think it is because in table 2 String & Integer Value both are available.

Please find my below VBA Code and guide how can i execute inner join for the same.

```
Sub sql()


sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Name],[Sheet3$].[Names] FROM" & _
"[Sheet3$] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet1$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Sr]"

sq = SQL_query(sql_string)

end sub


Function SQL_query(ByRef sql_string As Variant)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = sql_string

rs.Open strSQL, cn ''Here i am getting error...


Sheet5.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Function
```

Comment: is it definitely connecting to the source? Has your file name got spaces in it? If so I don't think you've handled the spaces in your `strCon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the sql query to ensure that both `Sr` are compared as strings

```
sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet3$].[Names] FROM [Sheet3$] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON CStr([Sheet1$].[Sr])=CStr([Sheet3$].[Sr])"
```